# Why Numpy.array is slower than build-in list for fetching sub list

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, numpy

I'm going to improve the performance of my code snippet which will frequently getting sub-array recursively.

So I used numpy.array instead of build-in list. Because, as I know, when fetching the sub-array, numpy.array don't copy the orginal list.

But when I changed to numpy.array, the performance got worse. So I want to know the reason. Thanks!

Following is my code snippet and the execution times by using the different objects I got:

```
import timeit
stat = ''' 
import numpy
def func(a):
    a[len(a)-1] += 1
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    else:
        return func(a[1:len(a)])
a1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
a2=numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Execution time with build-in list: {0}".format(timeit.timeit('func(a1)', setup = stat, number = 1000))
    print "Execution time with Numpy array: {0}".format(timeit.timeit('func(a2)', setup = stat, number = 1000))
```

And on my 64-bit mac(Python 2.7.6 + Numpy 1.8.0rc1) the output is:

```
Execution time with build-in list: 0.00507998466492
Execution time with Numpy array: 0.0195469856262
```

Comment: It may not copy the original list, but you still need to create a new numpy array which contains a reference into the original, which apparently is more expensive than creating a new list. You might try testing this with a *much* larger list/array.

Comment: Building on chepner, how does the time change as the array size increases? If his hypothesis is correct, then the list runtime won't change significantly, but the array runtime will increase linearly.

Comment: @chepner It seems you are right. I tested and numpy array is faster in large array than built-in list. But could you explain why it is apparently more expensive of creating a reference of new numpy array than creating a new list?

Comment: To be specific, with array of size 30 two this methods take same time to execute. With array of 100, numpy 2x faster. With array of 1000, numpy 7x faster. With array of 1000000, numpy ~20000x faster!

Comment: I don't know much about `numpy`; my assumption is that an `array` object is much more complicated than a `list` object to setup in order to provide fast operations on its data. a5kin's data seems to agree with this; you need a large data set before the efficiency of its operations overtakes its start-up cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all guys' answers and comments for this question, you have shown valuable info to me to make this answer.

The answer is this. The reason, which caused bad performance of numpy array in my quesion, is that **accessing to individual items and assigning to built-in type on numpy array is slower than on built-in list**. And, actually, the performance gain of fetching sub-array of numpy array than built-in list do exist. But the gain is too small in short array, e.g. array with len = 10 in my example, so the small gain was overtaken by the lost is this line: `a[len(a)-1] += 1` in which we have accessed individual items and converting between built-in type int.

---

Following code proved the reason:

```
import numpy
from timeit import timeit
stat = ''' 
import numpy
a1 = range(4000)
a2 = numpy.array(a1)
i = 0
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_times = 1000
    print '1. {0:.8f}'.format(timeit('a1[i]', setup = stat, number = test_times))
    print '2. {0:.8f}'.format(timeit('a2[i]', setup = stat, number = test_times))
    print '3. {0:.8f}'.format(timeit('i += a1[i]; ++i', setup = stat, number = test_times))
    print '4. {0:.8f}'.format(timeit('i += a2[i]; ++i', setup = stat, number = test_times))
    print '5. {0:.8f}'.format(timeit('a = a1[i:len(a1)]; ++i', setup = stat, number = test_times))
    print '6. {0:.8f}'.format(timeit('a = a2[i:len(a2)]; ++i', setup = stat, number = test_times))
```

The running result in my mac is following:

```
1. 0.00005913
2. 0.00017881
3. 0.00008607
4. 0.00084305
5. 0.01492000
6. 0.00053406
```

---

We can get these from the above result:

1. *1 vs 2*: Numpy array is slower when accessing individual item than built-in list.
2. *2 vs 4*: It seems need data conversion, which spend additional time, when assign data of item in numpy array to built-in type(int). For built-in list, the time spend for that is much little.
3. *5 vs 6*: Numpy truly saved much time when fetching sub-array comparing with built-in list.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the same execution times if you modify your two last lines of code as follows:

```
print "Execution time with build-in list: {0}".format(timeit.timeit(
    'func(a1)', setup = stat, number = 1000), 'gc.enable()')
print "Execution time with Numpy array:   {0}".format(timeit.timeit(
    'func(a2)', setup = stat, number = 1000), 'gc.enable()')
```

where in both cases we allowed *timeit* to switch on so-called *garbage collection*, i.e. the process of freeing memory when it is not used anymore. The abovementioned modification returns, e.g.:

```
Execution time with build-in list: 0.00580596923828
Execution time with Numpy array:   0.00822710990906
```

to be of the same order of magnitude. According to the documentation of *timeit* "by default, it temporarily turns off garbage collection during the timing. The advantage of this approach is that it makes independent timings more comparable. This disadvantage is that garbage collection may be an important component of the performance of the function being measured."

There is a thin understanding what method, i.e. with or without garbage collection, should be used and when. Please also note, that you will obtain much longer times if you apply time.time() block from *time* module.

Comment: Could you explain these 2 questions about your answer?

Comment: 1. Could you explain why gc could affect the time consuming and the reason for which they spend same time after applying gc?
2. Why time.time() will obtain much longer times?